# How to print through google cloud print on small receipt printer in php?

Tags: php, pdf, printers, google-cloud-print

I have tested the demo on regular size Canon LBP 2900 printer by adding it on google cloud print account it worked pretty well, but now I need to print the same thing on receipt printer. Is google cloud print allow to print through small printer & is there any need to process on pdf document to adapt on small size. So any one done this before.

**Here is my sample code which I have tested on regular size printer:**

```
<script>  
 function cloud_print() {
var gadget = new cloudprint.Gadget();
gadget.setPrintButton(
    cloudprint.Gadget.createDefaultPrintButton("print_button_container")); // div id to contain the button
//gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "");
gadget.setPrintDocument("application/pdf", "PDF Doc" );
gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", "http://localhost/pos/test.pdf");
var btn = document.getElementById("cl-print");
//gadget.setPrintButton(btn);
gadget.openPrintDialog();

}
</script>

<button id="cl-print" onclick="cloud_print()">Print it!</button>
```

Comment: Id say set this line: 
`gadget.setPrintDocument("url", "Test Page", myVar);` (and the `openDialog()` one) inside a ajax request, assuming "myVar" is the result of your request, in this case `http://localhost/pos/test.pdf`

Comment: Wondering, have you found a receipt printer that supports Google Cloud Print ?